# Компоновка виджетов в QHBoxLayout

Tags: python, pyqt5

Мне нужно чтобы виджет `self.choice` был на полную ширину(т.е. сейчас он как будто за приложением)[image]
А нужно чтобы выгладило примерно так (но так получается за счет использовании `setFixedSize(x, y)`)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как реализовать так же только без использования `setFixedSize(x, y)`?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui


class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setWindowTitle('python')
        self.setFixedSize(1000, 700)

        self.choice = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget(self)
        # self.choice.setFixedSize(700, 700)
        self.choice.setHeaderLabels(["1", "5", "7", "4", "2", "a", "ответ"])
        self.choice.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Times New Roman', 13))
        for item in range(10):
            tree_caption = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(["asdasdasd", "asdasdasd","asdasdasd",
                                                      "asdasdasd","asdasdasd","asdasdasd","asdasdasd",])
            self.choice.addTopLevelItem(tree_caption)
        lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        lay.addWidget(self.choice, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignRight | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.setLayout(lay)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: "естественный" размер QTreeWidget не определяется его содержимым. Если хотите по содержимому размер определять, то руками считать придётся (выставить у каждой секции `QHeaderView::ResizeToContents` и обновлять при изменении содержимого).

Comment: @jfs можете легенький пример привести а то не могу найти как конкретно это сделать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы руками подстроить ширину QTreeWidget под его содержимое:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
ncolumns = 10
w = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget()
w.setHeaderLabels(map(str, range(ncolumns)))
w.header().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
for item in range(ncolumns):
    w.addTopLevelItem(
        QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem([
            'abcdefghijkl', 'abcdefghijk', 'abcdefghij', 'abcdefghi',
            'abcdefgh', 'abcdefg', 'abcdef', 'abcde', 'abcd', 'abc'
        ]))
width = sum(w.columnWidth(i) + 3 for i in range(w.columnCount()))
w.resize(width, w.sizeHint().height())

w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

- ResizeToContents режим индивидуальные столбцы под содержимое подгоняет
- ширина QTreeWidget (`width`) вычисляется суммированием ширины столбцов
- выставляется начальный размер.

[image: qtreeview width resizetocontents]

Comment: `w.setHeaderLabels(map(str, range(ncolumns)))` можно заменить на `w.setColumnCount(ncolumns)`

Comment: @gil9red: можно, но несколько другой результат (1-10 vs. 0-9)

Comment: только у программистов нумерация с 0 начинается :) в том же экселе -- с 1

Comment: а вот с компоновкой как делать, виджет все равно остается как бы спрятанным если использовать как в моем примере `QHBoxLayout`?

Comment: @Twiss попробуйте `w.setMinimumWidth(width)` или sizeHint() метод переопредилить.

Comment: `setMinimumWidth(width)` помог